# Getting parameter menu in QGIS modeler to appear?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I lost, by accident, the parameter menu in QGIS 2.14 Graphic Modeler.

Is there any tip for how can i get it back.

[image]

Comment: Try to move your mouse over the left-hand side of the window until you get the re-size handle - one is for the main window, one is for the paramters window - drag the re-size handle to the right until you see the paramter window re-appear...

Comment: Glad it was that easy!!!

Comment: I did it once but i didn't drag it long enough to show! I thought it was a programm error. But everything is perfect now! thnx

Comment: @DPSSpatial - Should post your comment as an **answer** :)

Comment: @Joseph done...

Answer (score 2):

Try to move your mouse over the left-hand side of the window until you get the re-size handle - one is for the main window, one is for the paramters window - drag the re-size handle to the right until you see the paramter window re-appear...

Comment: @DionisiaKoutsi please accept the answer if it solves your problem